# postgres : get the last two messages to a member from conversation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table below, it's a conversation between two members sender_id and receiver_id:

| id | msg | recordedentry | sender_id | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gaya | false | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | Massi | true | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | USA | false | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | Yes | true | 3 | 7 |
| 5 | Today | true | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | Bonjour Michel | false | 3 | 7 |
| 7 | Salut Youva | false | 7 | 3 |
| 8 | bla bla bla | false | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | Go go go | false | 7 | 3 |

For a member id=3, I would like to write in a single query, which can retrieve:
For the last two recordedentry=true of the list retrieve the id of the correspondent, and for these two coreespondant retrieve the last two messages

To have the following result at the end

| id | msg | recordedentry | sender_id | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Today | true | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | Salut Youva | false | 7 | 3 |
| 8 | bla bla bla | false | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | Go go go | false | 7 | 3 |

I wrote the query which can retrieve the last two messages with recordedentry=true:

```
select * from message where recordedentry=true and (sender_id=3 or receiver_id=3) order by id desc limit 2;
```

I'm stuck on it :-/

can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found how to build in one query, but for now I've done it in two queries:

The first one :

```
select * from message where recordedentry=true and (sender_id=3 or receiver_id=3) order by id desc limit 2;
```

So I got the list of correspondent ids, in my case 7 and 1. And from there I made a second request:

```
(select * from message where (sender_id=3 and receiver_id=1) or (sender_id=1 and receiver_id=3) order by id desc limit 2) union (select * from message where (sender_id=3 and receiver_id=7) or (sender_id=7 and receiver_id=3) order by id desc limit 2)
```

Maybe it will help someone :-)

But if you have a better solution, I'm interested!